# CSS formatting horizontally level login boxes/button

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>             
  <div class="loginText makeInline2">
    <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "email", :size => 20 %></br>
    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="loginText makeInline2">
    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "password", :size => 20 %></br>
    Forgot your password?
  </div>

  <div class="makeInline2">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

CSS:

```
.loginText {
color: #DCDCDC;
}

.loginText label {
font-weight:normal;
}

.makeInline2  {
display:inline-block;
padding: 20px; 
}
```

Produces:

[image: css and view produces the following]

Would like to do a couple of things with the above image via CSS:

First you can see that the password box is just slightly lower than the email box and the login button lower than both the input boxes. Any ideas on how to make them completely level vertically (like the facebook login looks like for example)? In other words bring the tops of both the password textbox and login button to the horizontal line in the below picture:

[image]

Lastly, any idea on how to close the horizontal gap (represented by 'x' in the below picture) between the email textbox, password textbox, and login button:

[image]

Comment: was able to close the gap 'x' by using padding-left: 0px; Just looking for 1st part of question now.

Comment: vertical-align: text-top; worked for other part of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
padding-left: 0px;
vertical-align: text-top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work.

```
    .makeInline2{
     float:left; 
     padding-left:0px;         
     }
```